# Firebase - user properties are shown in "DebugView" but not in "User Properties" (not even after days)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Title say it all, it is very weird. This is my code:

```
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(ctx);
analytics.setUserProperty(MY_PROP, "test");
```

That is pretty much all. I can clearly see this in Android studio logging and sending, also receiving them in Firebase console in section DebugView - but even after 4 days, they are still not shown in User Properties.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you have to register the User property in the "User properties" tab in Firebase console - Analytics. It wont appear just after you call the setUserProperty() method, as mentioned here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=android

Sometimes, even the DebugView don't show the property if you haven't create the property in firebase console.

Answer (score 2):

This has updated slightly and they're now called [Custom dimensions in the user interface](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489&visit_id=637646001750147825-2554615152&rd=1#create-property)

It also mentions it can take up to 48h for a custom dimension to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, that's what got me confused. Cause I couldn't find the User Properties tab that I saw in the video tutorial